# UserControl hidden, Zindex misused?

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, visibility

In my main page I try to show a list of stuff, and on this stuff a userControl as an overlay. In fact I never see it. (In the design view, my userControl is oaky)

**XAML MainPage**

```
    <Grid>
      <Grid x:name="MyPage">
        <!-- All this part is visible -->
        //Button
        //Button
        //nice Pic
        //Button
      </Grid>
      <cat:CatPagecontrol x:Name="CatTool" Visibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
          <cat:CatPagecontrol.Transitions>
              <TransitionCollection>
                  <PopupThemeTransition/>
              </TransitionCollection>
          </cat:CatPagecontrol.Transitions>
      </cat:CatPagecontrol>
<!-- EDIT I remove the Grid "CatGrid" And the ZIndex -->
   </Grid>
```

I try to switch the ZIndex, no results.

**C# File**

```
public MainView()
{
   this.CatTool = new CatPagecontrol();
   //this.CatTool.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}

private void showCatSelector()
{
   this.CatTool.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

After that I need that one of my buttons show the overlay when clicked.

If you know how to show it, I'm yours. Thanks.
edit : solution find.

Comment: What happens when you remove this line `this.CatTool = new CatPagecontrol();` from the constructor? Since you declared this control in XAML, there is no need to create it again in code behind.

Comment: I add this one after seeing that nothing append. And If I remove it, there are no change.

Comment: And all the ZIndex stuff is redundant and should be removed.

Comment: So remove it, because it shouldn't be there. Why you use `Width="Auto"`? I think it may cause some problems (maybe Auto means 0?). Also, remove `Canvas.ZIndex` parts because they only work inside `Canvas` control.

Comment: Nothing append... In fact I don't know if the control is hidden, out of the page or under the page.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot to show how it looks in Visual Studio designer? You said that in design view your control is ok.

Comment: I've just patch the problem. I've put my InitializeComponant in the wrong constructor. Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voila !

I've find my problem :

```
public CatPagecontrol()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}
```

I just Initialized in the correct section.